# Where is Srivatsa symbol mentioned and how does the authentic symbol look like?

Tags: vishnu, lakshmi, symbols

From what I have found, the Srivatsa symbol in Hinduism is the mark on the chest of Sri Hari Vishnu where Mata Laxmi resides.

Which scripture or authentic source has clear description or a pictorial form of the auspicious symbol mentioned? How does the symbol look like? What is the esoteric meaning and significance of the symbol in Hinduism?